# How to force User to logout when the same User login from another browser

Tags: jsf, session, logout

My customer want me to implement a function which forces the User logout automatically, when the same User login from another browser. Ex:  After user login via Firefox browser successfully, the IE session will be discontinued.  Any further action will be redirected to login page.

Any idea?

Comment: you can implement a request filter, which accesses a singleton/static session map, keyed with user id and valued with session id. if the session id of current request's user does not match the stored one, you will force it to logout.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a session listener that will map the username with a jsessionId  ( thus the session object)

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        se.getSession().getId();
        applicationScopeMap.put(se.getSession().getId(), se.getSession());
    }
...
```

then when the user log in you should also map his username with the session id and check if he have already a session on the map and invalid it:

```
public String doLogin(){

        String sessionId = userSessionMap.get(username);
        if(sessionId != null){
            applicationScopeMap.get(sessionId).invalidate();
        }else{
            userSessionMap.put(username, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionId(true));
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: could you explain this line?
applicationScopeMap.put(se.getSession().getId(), se.getSession());

Comment: applicationScopeMap is a Map<String, HttpSession> that you will use to put the session with the session id as a key.